# Taxonomy access control (TAC) for SAAS based solution in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

My use case scenario is as follows.

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called "Company" with unique terms "Company 1", Company 2" and so on. Each node in my setup has a term reference for this as mandatory. Similarly, every user is associated with one term with a custom field.

What I want is to restrict a user to only see/edit the nodes that are attached to the same term ID. e.g. If user A is associated with "Company 1", he/she can only view the nodes that are associated with "Company 1".

I am using "TAC" module to achieve this. But it only allows for the taxonomy based access control based on hard coded values whereas I am looking for dynamic reference to the tid in userfield.

PS: I am relatively new to Drupal

Answer (score 1):

Do it on your own. Use hook_node_access and write your own logic there:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x